# How can I wrap this woocommerce template php in a function?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to wrap this templated html in a function so I can hook it into 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title'. I have it working great as part of a template override with meta.php, I just cant seem to wrap it in a function.

Here is the code I'm using ->

```
<?php if ( ! in_category('accessories') && ( strpos(get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), 'show min max thc cbd', true), 'true') !== false ) ) : ?>

        <span class="thc_content_wrapper"><?php esc_html_e( 'THC:', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <span class="thc"><?php echo ( get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), 'min thc', true) ); ?><?php esc_html_e( '-', 'woocommerce' ); ?><?php echo ( get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), 'max thc', true) ); ?><?php echo ( get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), 'thc/cbd unit', true) ); ?></span></span>
        <span class="cbd_content_wrapper"><?php esc_html_e( 'CBD:', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <span class="cbd"><?php echo ( get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), 'min cbd', true) ); ?><?php esc_html_e( '-', 'woocommerce' ); ?><?php echo ( get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), 'max cbd', true) ); ?><?php echo ( get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), 'thc/cbd unit', true) ); ?></span></span>

    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if ( ! in_category('accessories') && ( strpos(get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), 'show min max thc cbd', true), 'false') !== false ) ) : ?>

        <span class="thc_content_wrapper"><?php esc_html_e( 'THC:', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <span class="thc"><?php echo ( get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), 'thc', true) ); ?><?php echo ( get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), 'thc/cbd unit', true) ); ?></span></span>
        <span class="thc_content_wrapper"><?php esc_html_e( 'CBD:', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <span class="cbd"><?php echo ( get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), 'cbd', true) ); ?><?php echo ( get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), 'thc/cbd unit', true) ); ?></span></span>

    <?php endif; ?>
```

And here is an image of what this code does on the single product pages. [image: Custom added post meta]

Now, I have a function in code snippets that looks like this ->

```
function display_test_markup() {

    esc_html_e( 'THC:', 'woocommerce' );

}
    
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'display_test_markup', 10 );
```

And does this -> [image: product box meta]

I just cant get it to display the get_post_meta() part.

Comment: I'm slowly winning.

Comment: I've read this several times and still don't know what you're asking. Could you provide the HTML out put you're expecting along with the current HTML output you're currently getting with your code?

Answer (score 0):

```
function lf_display_product_box_meta() {

    $id = get_the_ID();
    $display_min_max = get_post_meta( $id, 'show min max thc cbd', true );
    $unit = get_post_meta( $id, 'thc/cbd unit', true );
    if ( strpos( $display_min_max, 'true') !== false ) {
        $min_thc = get_post_meta( $id, 'min thc', true );
        $max_thc = get_post_meta( $id, 'max thc', true );
        $min_cbd = get_post_meta( $id, 'min cbd', true );
        $max_cbd = get_post_meta( $id, 'max cbd', true );
        
        if ( ! in_category( 'accessories' ) ) {
        
        echo '<div class="box_cannabinoid_wrapper">THC:' . $min_thc . '-' . $max_thc . $unit . '<br>CBD:' . $min_cbd . '-' . $max_cbd . $unit . '</div>';
            
        }
        
    }
    
    if ( strpos( $display_min_max, 'false') !== false ) {
        $thc = get_post_meta( $id, 'thc', true );
        $cbd = get_post_meta( $id, 'cbd', true );
        
        if ( ! in_category( 'accessories' ) ) {
        
            echo '<div class="box_cannabinoid_wrapper">THC:' . $min_thc . '-' . $max_thc . $unit . '<br>CBD:' . $min_cbd . '-' . $max_cbd . $unit . '</div>';
        
        }
        
    }
    
}
    
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'lf_display_product_box_meta', 10 );
```